# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to install vanilla forums on my Mac, and for this I just created a database and a user from the MySQL command line:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE vanilla;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create user 'vanilla_user3'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'vanilla_password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'vanilla_user3'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

So I try to connect using the following code:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","vanilla_user3","vanilla_password","vanilla");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

but unfortunately, I get an error saying

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /Users/kramer65/Sites/vanilla/info.php on line 3
>   Failed to connect to MySQL: No such file or directory

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 224, accepted):

Alright, I just found the solution. The problem turned out to be that the host shouldn't have been `localhost`, but `127.0.0.1`. I always thought `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` was the same, but it turned out to be different.

So maybe as a tip for future users, always use the ip when in doubt.

Comment: The answer by mohitmayank is correct. If `localhost` does not work, you need to tell PHP where to find your mysql socket file.

Comment: see my comment to #Adam's Nov 21 '16 answer

Comment: Similar issue but simpler: MySQL not starting can cause the same error. Client's server hadn't been rebooted in months, after reboot mysql wasn't running and nobody thought to check. Too worried about all the codebase and "who caused this bug". lol (Just because Apache  is up and you can ssh into the server, that's not a guarantee MySQL is up, too)

Comment: @TheSatinKnight I observe this same error like once in a couple of months too, which seems to be related to what you say, as MySQL server being temporarily unavailable at that exact moment.

Comment: This answer worked for me partially. I also had to define [mysql_native_password](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50776838/11932012).

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem but the issue was something related to `php.ini` file.

I had to edit these two lines in `/etc/php.ini` (or wherever your `php.ini` is located):

```
mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Restart apache server to make sure the changes are reflected.

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: This is correct answer for using socket instead TCP/IP.

Comment: mysql.sock was located at /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock for me'

Comment: Follow this up by using the instructions here for Mac users https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219970/warning-mysql-connect-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-vi

Answer (score 14):

If using docker use the mysql container name as host name of mysql. For example if this is the docker compose file:

```
mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysqlHost
    ports:
        - "33099:3306"
```

Host name will be `mysqlHost` and port will be `3306` and not `33099`!

If you are not using docker compose, `docker ps` reveals the running container names.

On a different note, to connect mysql server on the host machine from docker, connect to `host.docker.internal`:

```php
$conn = mysqli_connect("host.docker.internal", "mysqluser", "mysqlpass", "dbname");
```

Answer (score 8):

Let's say your MAMP MySQL Port is set to 8889 like it is by default. Sometimes `localhost` alone is not enough in which case you have to put the MySQL port in there too so you would do `localhost:8889` or `localhost:{whatever your MySQL port number is}`. I'm still new to MySQL so I don't know the reason why, but to anyone out there who recently got the message: `Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in ...` adding the MySQL port number onto localhost was the fix for me.

Comment: In what I consider to be a bug, localhost does indeed need to have the port (even if it is the default of 3306) added to it in the $host parameter but no other hostname does.  So you would use "localhost:3306" for the $host parameter. Other hostnames and IP addresses will make use of the $port parameter.  But the $port parameter is ignored if $host is 'localhost'.  I believe the problem traces to something in the PHPdoc for __construct(): "When possible, pipes will be used instead of the TCP/IP protocol".

Answer (score 3):

find `php.ini` file in `/opt/lampp/etc/`
then edit:

```
mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

after this in your DB connect file change from localhost to `127.0.0.1`. everything will be ok. however, if you attempted the `config.inc.php` file, make sure its all set to `127.0.0.1`, not localhost.

Comment: this is the right answer. when providing "localhost" as the server name mysql tries to connect via the socket file. There should be a missconfiguration between php.ini default_socket, and the my.cnf socket setting

Answer (score 0):

As additional verifications, check if `ipv6` is enable on your localhost environment, so disable it.

Some times localhost envirement aren't ready to work with ipv6, mainly when your local machine queries a remote ip on the internet.

On Windows machines, comment also the `::1 localhost` entry from the `hosts` file.

If you can, a good way to check if that is the issue is:

Execute the built-in web server from php with:

```
php -S localhost:7000
```

Now, access your script by browser and check on console if the response comes from the loopback address ipv4 `127.0.0.1` or from the loopback ipv6 `::1`.

What we don't want:

```
[Thu Mar  9 10:58:12 2023] [::1]:51636 Accepted
[Thu Mar  9 10:58:37 2023] [::1]:51636 [200]: GET /my_script.php
[Thu Mar  9 10:58:37 2023] [::1]:51636 Closing
```

What we want:

```
[Thu Mar  9 11:12:10 2023] 127.0.0.1:58730 Accepted
[Thu Mar  9 11:12:10 2023] 127.0.0.1:58728 [200]: GET /my_script.php
[Thu Mar  9 11:12:10 2023] 127.0.0.1:58728 Closing
```

*If you can't run the built-in server, check the logs!*

Note that there is no problem about using ipv6 with php or MySQL, but your environment needs to be ready to it.

Answer (score 0):

**When running containers on the same network** defined in `docker-compose.yml`, to connect from any container to the MySQL container, **use the service name** as the hostname.

For example, **in the following case**, inside *service2*, **use** `"mysql1"` **instead of** `"localhost"` **or** `"127.0.0.1"`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql1:
    ...
    networks:
      - docker-network 

  service2:
    ...
    networks:
      - docker-network 

networks:
  docker-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score -1):

set port in host:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost:**3306**","vanilla_user3","vanilla_password","vanilla");
```