# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /Applications/mampstack-7.1.10-1/apache2/htdocs/insert.php on line 2

Tags: php, mysql

If I code like this:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "111111", "???");
mysqli_query($conn, "
    INSERT INTO ?? (
        title,
        description,
        created
    ) VALUES (
        'MySQL',
        'MySQL is ....',
        NOW()
    )");
?>
```

then the webpage alert like this

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /Applications/mampstack-7.1.10-1/apache2/htdocs/insert.php on line 2

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /Applications/mampstack-7.1.10-1/apache2/htdocs/insert.php on line 3
```

What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My database user exists, but I still get an (HY000/2002): No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073168/my-database-user-exists-but-i-still-get-an-hy000-2002-no-such-file-or-direct)

Comment: mysqli_connect - the fourth parameter is the name of the database you want to use.

Comment: I had such a problem after running PHP-FPM in a CHROOT.