# PhpMyAdmin running on Mac, but can't get php to connect

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection

```
Mac Catalina
Mysql server 8.02 community server
phpmyadmin 5.0.2
php 7.47
```

Phpmyadmin is working fine. See screen capture:

[image]

From phpmyadmin, I was able to create a local user and db, both called test on localhost.

However, I am not capable of connecting to it from my php program:

```
<?php
$db_creds = array();
$db_creds['user'] = 'test';
$db_creds['pwd'] = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$db_creds['name'] = 'test';
$db_creds['host'] = 'localhost';

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_creds['host'], $db_creds['user'], $db_creds['pwd'], $db_creds['name']);
```

gives me the following error message:

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /Users/my-mac/Dropbox/joe/development/php/test_2.php on line 8 (last line)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try changing your `host` to `127.0.0.1` and see if that works? [*Reference*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20074372/2518525)

Comment: This seems to work. Any explanation?

Comment: Using `127.0.0.1` forces a TCP connection. The default for `locahost` is to try and use a local socket which seems to be set incorrectly for your environment. You can configure the default value via `mysqli.default_socket` or pass in a specific value into the `mysqli` constructor (6th argument)

Comment: Exactly what @Phil said above - great explanation!