# PHP script cannot connect to MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a straight forward script that is trying to connect to a MySQL database.

When I run the script, I get the error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShopSite\submitReg.php on line 16
>   Failed to connect.

The connection code is:

```
$server="127.0.0.1";
$db="shop";
$user="root";
$password="";

$conn=mysqli_connect($server,$user,$password,$db) or die("Failed to connect");
```

I can connect to phpMyAdmin and edit the database on there just fine.  I am using XAMPP and running it locally.

When I go to user accounts, it says there is no password for root.  I looked in the config file and there are no passwords set.  I haven't set a password for anything.

I haven't went in and fiddled with settings, or created any new accounts.  It was working fine (never used to get this problem), then it just started with this.  I reinstalled XAMPP, still giving me this issue.

I don't get why it says using password "YES".

I've been at this for hours trying to fix it.  I've looked through lots of threads.  Not all necessarily apply to me, as I am running it locally, and haven't been going in and making new user accounts.  Everything is default.

Before I reinstalled, I tried creating a new user account and giving it the necessary privileges.  I gave it a password too.  Didn't work.

I don't get why it is doing this, and am not knowledgeable enough to fix it myself.  Any help is much appreciated, so that it can go back to connecting.

Comment: The fact that it says "localhost" and "using password: YES" makes me think you are not looking at the right code block.

Comment: have you tried adding a user with a passwords and logging into the db? I would also try logging in directly with a mysqli client like heidisql

Comment: @Devon, how do you mean?

Comment: If the code block you were looking at corresponded to the error, it would say "127.0.0.1" and "using password: NO".  Are you sure the code you posted is line 16 of C:\xampp\htdocs\ShopSite\submitReg.php?

Comment: @GuyLouzon I had tried that before and it didn't work.  Tried it this time and it did.  Thanks for suggesting it again.  No idea why it didn't like it before.

Comment: possible duplicate, check this out!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668275/cant-connect-to-mysql-with-php

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 $server="127.0.0.1";
```

by

```
$server="localhost";
```

Comment: Verify the permission tables (reloading grants if required) on the server and that you're connecting to the correct server.

Comment: Try with this :  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database_name")or die("Failed to connect");

Answer (score 0):

I used XAMPP for a while and it worked quite good for me,
 i think the default password for your mysql server is not set to `''`, so i guess 
if you change the root password and try accessing your database using the new password, it should work.

## Updating the root password

To update the `root` use password, you have to go by these steps:

1. Open the XAMPP Control Panel
2. Click on the MySQL button
3. After the MySQL console has loaded, execute this query:

   SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('pass');`

After that, change the `$password` variable to the new password which
is in this case `pass`

## Adding a new user

You could also add a new user by executing this query:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'new-user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

While the username is `new-user` and the password is `password`.

I hope this helps.